# Office Add In with commands - strategy for complex SPA?

Tags: angularjs, ms-office, office365, office-js

Our office add in uses a backend service and is now getting commands.
Most of the commands will only work when the taskpane app is opened and logged in (SPA angular app context!).

We are facing the following problems with AddIn commands:

1. The taskpane is no more opend when inserting the add in and there is no way to open it by a command. (`AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` will only reopen taskpane when opening a document). *How to open the taskpane by a command?*
2. What to do with commands that are not executable when taskpane is closed?
   There is no way to disable commands - or check if taskpane is already opened.
3. How to detect if the current client will support add in commands?
   We want to streamline our app (remove those actions inside the app etc.).

Answer (score 0):

1. Most of the Office add-in samples in GitHub/OfficeDev have a button that opens the taskpane. The essential task is to set the Action element in the manifest to the type "ShowTaskpane". For an example, see the Word sample in this repo: [Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples).
2. I don't have an answer for this. You should consider making it a separate StackOverflow question. It is really a separate issue.
3. For information about how to test if the Office host supports commands see: [Specify Office hosts and API requirement sets](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) and [Add-in Commands Requirement Sets](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets). It can be done in the manifest or in the add-in's JavaScript.